# Select items with a class and tagname

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to use JS to find all items with an `A` tag, and the class `Titanic`. How would i go about this without querySelector. I want the method to be fast. So preferably no loops.

Comment: Apologies but, There's alot of resources on this question on SO, let alone the web.

Comment: I couldnt find any that didnt point to QuerySelector. So unless you can find such a link your comment is mood and your downvote is useless.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get away from loops.

You can use the `document.links` collection that already contain all the links in the page, and check the class name of each:

```
var el = [];
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if (document.links[i].className == 'Titanic') {
        el.push(document.links[i]);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TrhCG/

Note: The `links` collection only contains actual links, i.e. anchor tags (and area tags) with a `href` attribute. Also, the way to compare the class name only works if the element contains only that class name.

Comment: +1, but [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links) only contains links, the OP might want anchors to. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Good point, I was thinking about that. I added a note with the limitations of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByTagName() function to select anchor tags. You can check the classname using .classname property.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
                > -1) {
           /*Do something.*/
        }
    }
```

Life's much easier if you use jQuery though.

Comment: `('*')` when you could use `a`?

Comment: Cant it be done without a loop? And Jquery is easier, but slower.

Comment: Yes. You can use 'a', 'input' or anything of sorts.

Comment: javascript as such doesn't have a function to get classnames straight.